# browser unresponsive upon loading larger files

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I am download multiple json data files and then visualize that files using [D3](http://d3js.org) data charts. When I load the page it takes lot of time 2-3 minutes to download and visualize, even more on mobile devices. and browser shows a dialog for unresponsiveness. Is there a way to improve load time and handle the load time gracefully?

Every file is of few hundred (100 - 500) KBs and there are 20 - 200 files

Here is a sample code for line chart only

`drawLineChart` it downloads the json file and extract the data from it, `formatLineChartData` formats that data to input d3 and finally `lineChartConfig` draws the chart. similarly there are functions for bar charts, pie charts, word clouds and maps.

```
var drawLineChart           = function(lineChartData,  suffix, el){
    var n = lineChartData.length;
    var dataArray = []; 
    var labels= '';

    var allNull  =true; //  flag to check if every ajax does not return any data
    for (var i=0; i<n; i++){
        spark.loadCounterJSON(lineChartData[i].file + suffix,i,
        function(res){
            var data =res.values;
            if(data){
                if(lineChartData[res.counter].slug !== 'global'){
                    allNull = false;
                }
                var title = Object.keys(data.entities)[0];

                graphValues = data[title];
                if(graphValues!=''){
                    labels = data['properties'];
                    dataArray.push(
                        formatLineChartData(
                            graphValues, 
                            lineChartData[res.counter].name,
                            true
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
            if(res.counter === n  && !allNull){ // all outer ajax done;

                lineChartConfig(el, 
                    dataArray, 
                    false, 
                    true,
                    ''
                ,labels);
            }
        });
    }   
};



var formatLineChartData     = function(graphValues, key, xDataType){
    formatedData = [];  

    $.each(graphValues, function(i, v){
        value = {};
        if(xDataType !== undefined){ 
            value['x'] = new Date(v.x);
        }
        else {value['x']=v.x;}
        value['y']=parseInt(v.y)
        formatedData.push(value);
    });     
    return {values:formatedData,key:key};   
}

var lineChartConfig             = function (div, data, guideline, useDates, auxOptions,labels, width, height) {
        var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
            width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            //var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

            var x = d3.time.scale()
                .range([0, width]);

            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([height, 0]);

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom");

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("right");

            var line = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); }); 


            var svg = d3.select(div).append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                var dataResult;
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    dataResult = data[i].values;
                }
        //console.log(dataResult);
        dataResult.forEach(function(d) {
            d.x = new Date(d.x);
            d.y = d.y;
          });

                x.domain(d3.extent(dataResult, function(d) { return d.x; }));
                y.domain(d3.extent(dataResult, function(d) { return d.y; }));

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);


                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .call(yAxis)
                  .append("text")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 6)
                    .attr("dy", ".71em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "end");

                svg.append("path")
                    .datum(dataResult)
                    .attr("class", "line")
                    .attr("d", line);
}
```

Comment: How large is your data exactly? Did you consider loading it dynamically?

Comment: I edit the question. What do you mean by loading it dynamically?

Comment: What I meant was that maybe you could split your content in smaller pieces, load only a couple of these pieces initially and load the rest after the initial load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is figure out where the problem is. If you have profiling or performance tools you could try those, but the quick dirty way would probably just have your script echo when it finishes downloading a file, when it finishes creating a chart, etc with the current time. This should give you a rough idea of where your time is being spent.

To improve the download speed, you would need to either make the file smaller, not downloading files you don't need, or if the hold up is in the upload speed on your server rather than download speed at the client, improve your infrastructure.

To improve processing speed of the charts... you would need to optimize the code which if you are using a built API you might not have options for. But you definitely want to make sure you aren't making any redundant calls, and check the documentation for any optimization options. Your server side operations could also be improved by multithreading/multiprocessing if possible and you have the hardware to support it.

As for handling it gracefully, the general principle should be to use asynchronous operations as much as possible. For example, if you are loading multiple charts, start each as a progress bar that updates as the data downloads (etc), and then display a chart as soon as it's available. It won't make the process go any faster, but it will keep the page responsive and keep the user informed.